# Part of ripple effect is not fading away on image button when clicked

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I have an ImageButton and I'm setting its background like below to produce ripple effect:

```
  android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

my ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibn_option"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

**Problem**
When I press this ImageButton a ripple like effect appears but a part of it is not fading away when I lift my finger up.

I'm also attaching images:

[image: When I press ImageButton]

[image: after I lift my finger up]

Comment: Try using foreground instead : android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` as a `android:background` put it on `android:foreground` as follows :

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

This is how I did it:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibn_option"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
         />
```